# Python: Compare file name after deleting some characters from the name

Tags: python, rename, filenames

Python:

I'm trying to compare file names in a directory after stripping some n characters from the name. If the file name exists after the strip, then it will add a number to the end of the name.

I created a code that renames all the file names in the directory, but I'm having trouble trying to do the comparison AND THEN renaming due to the existing same file name after the strip.

```py
import os 

def main(): 
    i = 0

    for filename in os.listdir("C:\\Users\User\Desktop\Tests"): 

        try:
            dirName != filename
            print (filename)

        except dirName == filename:
            dst ="dup" + str(i) + ".txt"
            src = dirName 
            dst ='Test'+ dst

        # rename() function will 
        # rename all the files 
            os.rename(src, dst) 
            i += 1

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 

    # Calling main() function 
    main()
```

I get it to rename the files directly but unable to do the comparison with the file names THEN renaming if it is the same name. New to python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    i = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\User\Desktop\Tests"):
             for filename in files:
                for filename2 in files :
                    if filename != filename2: # if your file name is not repetitious you will pass it and compare next one 
                        #print(filename)
                        continue
                # if a repetitious filename found your code for rename it will come up
                dst ="dup" + str(i) + ".txt"
                src = filename 
                dst ='Test'+ dst
                os.rename(src, dst)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to remove characters from the filename and then do the comparison. I tried to do `for filename in files: filename = filename.split[5:]` to remove the first 5 characters from the filename but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried   `filename = filename[5:]` instead ?

Comment: Yea. I have couple of filenames like aaaaaText.txt, bbbbbText.txt, cccccText.txt. When I run the code it doesnt rename my files.

Comment: now i see the name of your inputs i got it . that's because of this line   `if filename != filename2:` .this line says that if there is not some exact same names in your directory so there is no need to change the name of the file .  you should change filename1 and filename2 just like `filename = filename[5:]` . so you can compare some part of file names that you want.